# Trying to implement HTML & CSS to existing JavaScript: The interface comes out completely differently

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a login screen for a client, I am trying to implement it into their system but the CSS doesn't seem to behave properly in the same way it did before.

I've tried various div grouping, css tags and I can't seem to get it to work the same.

Here is the already existing JavaScript:

```
render() {
    const loginFailNotice = this.state.loginFail ? (
      <p className="loginFailNotice">Login Failed, Please Try Again</p>
    ) : null;
    return (
      <div className="loginArea">
        <div className="loginBox2">
          <input className="loginboxtype"
            placeholder="E-mail"
            onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
            onKeyPress={this.handleEnterPress}
          />
          {loginFailNotice}

        </div>
        <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLogin}>Login</LoginButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My HTML:

```
    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100 p-t-85 p-b-20">
                <form autocomplete="off" class="login100-form validate-form">
                    <span class="login100-form-avatar">
                        <img src="images/avatar-01.png" alt="AVATAR">
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-t-85 m-b-35" data-validate = "Enter email">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="email">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Email"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!--This is the button only-->
                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>


                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.container-login100-form-btn {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.login100-form-btn {
  font-family: Poppins-Medium;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #46b3d1;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0px rgba(69, 172, 219, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0px rgba(69, 172, 219, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0px rgba(69, 172, 219, 0.5);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0px rgba(69, 172, 219, 0.5);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0px rgba(69, 172, 219, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.login100-form-btn:hover  {
  background-color: #333333;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
```

I have used identical CSS in both scenarios as well as changing tags, divs etc to get different results but all have failed in replicating the original design

I expect it to look like this (http://prntscr.com/nsfjkd)

but it looks like this (http://prntscr.com/nsfjt1)

Comment: Without seeing the source code in action it's hard to determine why your code isn't working. You might have a selector missing or the CSS file isn't imported correctly.

Comment: As I see the CSS is missing the class for the input for example, or the button does not have a `border: 0;` to override the default border added by the browser. Try pasting the original CSS (the one that works).

Comment: You have only put the style for buttons. Where is the rest?